# Web Api GET method that has a nullable Guid possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC Web API get method that I'd like to be able to pass a nullable Guid as a parameter.  If I setup the GET with a "?Id=null" I get a 400 response.  I can pass a empty guid but that I'd rather not do that.

No matter what I change the URI to, "id=, id=null etc" it won't accept null.  Does anyone know how to make this work?

```
  [HttpGet]
  public User Get(Guid? Id)
```

Update Route config

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Full Http Get signature, sourceId is the param that id like to pass as null.

```
 [HttpGet]
  public IEnumerable<ActionItemsListViewModel> GetPagedList(int skip, int take, int page, int pageSize, [FromUri]List<GridSortInfo> sort, [FromUri] ActionItem.ActionItemStatusTypes? actionItemStatus, Guid? sourceId)
```

Found the problem, this filter was saying the ModelState was invalid.

```
public class ApiValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            var errors = actionContext.ModelState
                .Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                .Select(e => e.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage).ToList();

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, string.Join(" ", errors));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try not to pass anything?

Comment: @murilokunze Yes, and that does work, unfortunately the control I'm using with the api doesn't allow me to exclude the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to pass null to the Guid? when I use

- query string parameter:  api/values?id=null
- route parameter:  api/values/null

Controller:

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
 {
     public User Get(Guid? Id)
     { ... }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried the ?id=null in the query string and I'm getting back "The value 'null' is not valid for Nullable`1." Can you explain what you mean by "route parameter: api/values/null"?

Comment: I am not able to repro your issue when you you do ?id=null.  Does your ApiController looks like my repro ValuesController?

Comment: For the route parameter, I was using the 
a "DefaultApi" route (with routeTemaplte "api/{controller}/{id}) to map the {id} to null when I do this: api/values/null.  (This default route is defined in WebApiConfig.Register(...))

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  I updated the original question with some more details.  I simplified the original question to make it easier to understand, but I put more detail in now.  I'm using a telerik kendo grid that passes it's paging info to a web api method.

Comment: (1) Can you provide me the URL that causes the error "The value 'null' is not valid for Nullable`1."?  (2) What kind of type is ActionItem.ActionItemStatusTypes?  Is it a struct or an enum?  (It might be this parameter that is causing the error)

Comment: I found the problem... I have an ActionFilterAttribute that automatically checks the model state and if invalid returns an error.  For some reason I figured a null for Guid? would not invalidate the model, but I guess it does.  If you have any thoughts on how to correct this I'd appreciate it.  If not I greatly appreciate your help and to get by for now I'm just filtering out GETS.  I updated the original question with the filter.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
[HttpGet]
public User Get(Guid? Id = null)
```

Comment: If you use attribute based routing try:

    [Route("{id?}")]
    public User Get(Guid? Id = null)